# Should we say "the Kraken" or just "Kraken"?

Tags: definite-articles

From Wikipedia, "In Norwegian and Swedish, Kraken is the definite form of krake." Since "Kraken" is already the definite form, why do we add a "the" prior to "Kraken"? Or "Kraken" is a word taken from another language, therefore its grammatical property was dropped?

Comment: I've always heard it used with an article: "the Kraken" or "a Kraken." There's plenty of precedent, such as "the *hoi polloi,*" "the alcohol," "the azimuth," and "the almanac."

Comment: If you search Google, you can even find rare examples of expressions with three definite articles, such as "[the La Alhambra](https://www.tripadvisor.com/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g187441-d191078-i17337400-The_Alhambra-Granada_Province_of_Granada_Andalucia.html)."

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of the way the word entered the English language. In [the earliest appearances of the word I could find](https://books.google.com/books?id=sl80AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA292&dq=kraken&hl=tlh&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp57yR4NPMAhVEQSYKHQkBAoAQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=kraken&f=false) (1785), it's used as if "Kraken" were a species of fish, in the same paragraph as "the Sturgeon" and "the Whale." It's even implied that there are many Kraken plying the seas:

> Whether the vanishing island, Lemair, of which Captain Rodney went in search, was a Kraken, we submit to the fancy of our readers.

As "the Kraken" subsequently drifted from being a collective noun towards being a singular creature, the original construction stuck because it was familiar.

---

Also there's how we how we idiomatically use proper nouns. Saying "I saw the Kraken in the Pacific" sounds like I am referring to one individual from a class of creatures, whereas "I saw Kraken in the Pacific" makes it sound like the beast and I are on a first-name basis.

I don't think there's a hard rule here, since it's a mythical beast and thus in the province of creative writers who have leeway to bend words a little.

Comment: Just wanted to add my personal experience with the word. In any rpg game I have played since childhood, it has always been used as "the Kraken". Because in every world there was one Kraken.